# Why is youtube iframe causing "Loading failed for the <script> with source"

Tags: javascript, html

I am using youtube iframe for embeding on my site.  Currently I am in local development, but if I use iframe from youtube, it will give me the error message in console:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js”.
```

I dont have any adblockers on.

After the error, the rest of the page refuses to load and work correctly.  For example, I had javascript loaders at the end of the page, those did not work/load, I have since moved them to the header and now that works.  I am not doing anything magical, just including the iframe youtube has on their site right into the main page.

iframe usage:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/#" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're using the youtube iframe?

Comment: Just whatever youtube gives you.  I edited the embed src.  updated.

Comment: Are you using any sort of private browsing mode?

Comment: No I am not.  Must be some local thing where browser blocks things?

Comment: It sounds like something local is blocking the script, but I doubt that the script not loading could cause the rest of the page not to work.

Comment: To clarify, anything after the iframe fails to work.  I was loading javascript after the iframe and those did not load, but I moved them into <head> and now that works.  So it seems like the iframe is causing some weird issue, or the fail to load is causing the browser to not finish rendering the page?

Answer (score 1):

Which browser did you try?

I tried with firefox and chrome with the following results:

- Firefox with AdBlock Plus: Loading failed
- Firefox with ABP disabled (in the extensions page of Firefox): Worked
- Chrome without ABP: Worked

Comment: I used chrome and firefox, and I just tested it on a simple .html on my local machine. I still get Loading failed for the <script> with source. I am using ampps. Thanks for testing it though, I am guessing there is something on my end if this is working for you.  Just a thought, would it be possible my certs are not working with the ssl connection, therefore it stops?